# Get formData object from XHR if XHR object already formed

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, ckeditor

I want to customize XHR request in CKEditor 4. It provides fileUploadRequest event for this case. FileUploadRequest event provides me a XHR object through event object (var xhr = evt.data.fileLoader.xhr).

Before this event CKEditor append formData obj with "upload" field (which is containing file) to XHR object.

I want to get formed formData object from XHR object, then get file from 'upload', then form new formData with 'file' field and append file inside this. Then send XHR.

But how to get formData from XHR?

Answer (score 0):

I just lost CKEditor api. It provides interface requestData for this. Solution for my case:

```
evt.data.requestData.file = evt.data.requestData.upload;
delete evt.data.requestData.upload;
```